# how to read multiple log files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, fopen, textscan

I would like to open multiple log files, and concatenate them so that they make one big log file, from which I can then extract the information I need.

I would like matlab to open as many files, as there are in my folder, based on the name including a certain string.

here is my code so far:

```
pilotfiles = dir (['*PILOT*.log'])

for fil=1:length(pilotfiles)
    files{fil}=pilotfiles(fil).name;
end;
   files=char(files);

for fil = 1:length (files (:,1));
    clear logs;
    file_name = files (fil,:);
    noofColumns = 45;
    cs = repmat('%s', 1, noofColumns);
    fileID = fopen(deblank(file_name));
    logs = textscan(fileID,cs); 
    biglog = horzcat (logs {:}); 
    fclose (fileID);    
end
```

Of course, I would not be asking this question if the code worked.

file_name correctly returns names of all my files,  'logs' seems to read the contents of each of the files, but then my 'biglog' only contains the contents of the last log file .

Anybody has any ideas where am I making the mistake?

*NOTE: I am working on a MAC, this code is based on a code, which has worked on a PC*

Comment: I think you need to put `biglog` out of the `for` loop. Preset the `logs` as a cell of size 1x`length(files(:,1))`. And collect the logs in the element of the cell.

Comment: thank you. Can I confirm with you, that you meant adding `logs= 1:length(files(:,1))`  to the code  shouldn't I then change the `texscan` line as well ?

Comment: No... um... I think you need to read the basics in mathworks.com. Just to help you this time, i'll post the answer in a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

```
pilotfiles=dir('*PILOT*.log');
pilotfiles=pilotfiles(3:end);
N=numel(pilotfiles);
logs=cell(1,N);
cs=repmat('%s',1,45);
for i=1:N
    fid=fopen(fullfile(pilotfiles(i).folder,pilotfiles(i).name));
    logs{i}=textscan(fid,cs);
    logs{i}=[logs{i}{:}];
    fclose(fid);
end
biglog=[logs{:}];
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, this code does not work for me. I had to remove the reference to folder in the fid line (cause I have no such field in my pilotfiles), and now it stops on horzcat. "Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."
btw, I assume that line: `pilotfiles=pilotfiles(3:end)`; should read `pilotfiles=pilotfiles(1:end)`;

Comment: changed the last line to `biglog=vertcat (logs{:});`, and now it works. Big thanks for help!!!